# Installed App Authentication and Authorization

Tags: youtube, oauth-2.0

When authenticating a user for my vc++/mfc installed app with a localhost redirect via /o/oauth2/auth I do not get a code back, the response is always in the form `

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=6c4bc9dd35d125cf&hl=en_GB&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUcQpxtoKLUKgovAEs4EJ9rlbP-wBci36

this particular response was from the localhost redirect example on accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp.

My localhost authentication request looks like this,

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost

All the examples and my own code work fine with a OOB redirect but I would prefer to use the localhost redirect and then read the code from the url, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication, login, and upload all now work fine, I use the oob redirect and scan the html title rather than using localhost and scanning the url.